# Return MIN value in a range of cells, then lookup word from row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, min

The question sounds convoluted - but I can't think of a better way to explain it.

I have a formula in a workbook that finds the cheapest price when comparing car journeys.

Cells C4 to G4 have prices in them. In cell J5 is a formula to find the lowest value of these cells: [=MIN(C4:G4)].

Once this is calculated in J5, in J4 above it, I want to perform a name look-up (the car company names in the row above C4 to G4) that relates to this cheapest price found?

I would be eternally grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess without seeing the data layout but try this in J4.

```
=INDEX($C$3:$G$3, , MATCH(J5, $C$4:$G$4, 0))
```