# Return the value to the Left where the min is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup

As the title states, I am tryong to find the values to the left of where the value returned by `min()` is found. My Data is laid out as shown below, the columns I want to pull from are TP's so for row `Labor (L) = 1`, under the `LRATC` section the `TP` value should be the value to the left of where the `ATC` value of `7.5` is found, which would be `10`.

[image: Table of Excel Data]

I've tried using `=INDEX((J5,L5,N5,P5),MATCH(MIN(K5,M5,O5,Q5),(K5,M5,O5,Q5),0))` to create a range for it to use, however this causes a `#N/A` error seemingly inside the `MATCH()` operation.

Edit and clarification: in case you want to test things out for yourself, here is the original file [Hey! Click Me!](https://gvsu365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/cappsc_mail_gvsu_edu/EQ4VtKK7z2JDqDlQ-gCeNPMBpS6vAh2c6QHm1orB61sVfA?email=CAPPSC%40mail.gvsu.edu&e=Ia3QBF). The objective of this post was to have a place online where this problem could be documented as it was not easily found from the usual suspects. I am chiefly trying to troubleshoot the error in the `match()` call as mentioned above

Comment: Test just the match() first for a valid output. Once that works then test with index().

Comment: Match() gives a position as a result so usually index() expects a range...

Comment: @SolarMike match alone yields the `N/A` error I get

Comment: Then check match(), is the range correct? Is the target set correctly? Once you resolve that then you can progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return MIN value in a range of cells, then lookup word from row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930560/return-min-value-in-a-range-of-cells-then-lookup-word-from-row)

Comment: There are many Q & A on here about this, here is another and it has some very explanatory answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55148940/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did not give data I could copy and test, but I put something together:

K5  L5  M5  N5  O5  P5  Q5

2    22   3    33   4    44  5

and used:

```
=MATCH(MIN(K5,M5,O5,Q5),(K5:Q5),0)
```

which returns 1 as in position 1 in the range K5:Q5.

As for the index(), this works, but you need a "+1" to get the values you want:

```
=INDEX(K5:Q5,,MATCH(MIN(K5,M5,O5,Q5),(K5:Q5),0)+1)
```

Note the match() is put into the column argument in the index() function.

This now returns the result 22 as it should.

I would restructure the data as this may not be stable (work vertically...) but that is just me.

Comment: @calebcapps just as I showed, did you actually test it? I even showed the data I had to build since you did not provide sample data (an image does not count).

Comment: This works but goes to the right of the found cell, in case anyone else has this issue I just changed the `+1` to `-1`